# docker celery baby_api_celery_1 exited with code 1 without any error

Tags: docker, celery

docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  celery:
    build: ./
    command: celery -A settings worker -l info
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/antiquely
    links:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
ARG index_url

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /usr/src/antiquely

COPY ./ /usr/src/antiquely

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install python-mysqldb
RUN apt-get -y install python3-dev build-essential default-libmysqlclient-dev


RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python sweeper.py
```

here is my docker and docker-compose file
i am getting below error when doing `docker-compose up`

```
Creating network "baby_api_default" with the default driver
WARNING: Found orphan containers (antiquely, baby_api_tasker_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Creating baby_api_redis_1 ... done
Creating baby_api_celery_1 ... done
Attaching to baby_api_redis_1, baby_api_celery_1
redis_1   | 1:C 14 Oct 2021 18:07:03.439 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis_1   | 1:C 14 Oct 2021 18:07:03.439 # Redis version=6.2.4, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis_1   | 1:C 14 Oct 2021 18:07:03.439 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis_1   | 1:M 14 Oct 2021 18:07:03.440 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
redis_1   | 1:M 14 Oct 2021 18:07:03.441 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis_1   | 1:M 14 Oct 2021 18:07:03.441 # Server initialized
redis_1   | 1:M 14 Oct 2021 18:07:03.442 * Ready to accept connections
celery_1  | Running a worker with superuser privileges when the
celery_1  | worker accepts messages serialized with pickle is a very bad idea!
celery_1  | 
celery_1  | If you really want to continue then you have to set the C_FORCE_ROOT
celery_1  | environment variable (but please think about this before you do).
celery_1  | 
celery_1  | User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0
celery_1  | 
baby_api_celery_1 exited with code 1
```

It is not showing any error so it is very unclear
what can be the error and how to see exact error for this ?

please take a look

Comment: Do you need to `RUN adduser` in the Dockerfile to create a non-root user, then switch to that `USER` when the application runs?  (You shouldn't need to `chown` anything or otherwise alter permissions; your files will be owned by root, the application code will be prevented from overwriting them, and that's a good thing.)

Answer (score 0):

> celery_1  | Running a worker with superuser privileges when the
> celery_1  | worker accepts messages serialized with pickle is a very bad idea!
> celery_1  | 
> celery_1  | If you really want to continue then you have to set the C_FORCE_ROOT
> celery_1  | environment variable (but please think about this before you do).

The error information already tells you, the fix could be next:

**Option1: add a nobody user**

```
services:
  celery:
    user: nobody
    build: ./
```

You can also use `useradd` to add a new user, but a default `nobody` user enough in your scenario I guess.

**Option2: force to use root**

```
services:
  celery:
    environment:
    - C_FORCE_ROOT="true"
    build: ./
```